# Connecting from a SignalR client to a Spring websockets backend

Tags: java, spring, websocket, signalr, signalr.client

I have a client-server application written in .Net. The client connects to a SignalR hub in the backend service using the SignalR client.

In the next few months I'm going to be migrating my backend service from .Net to Java and Spring boot.
I have to maintain backwards compatibility for my clients.

My question is, is it possible to connect from a SignalR client to a non-SignalR websockets server?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. But it wouldn't be easy. You would need to implement the SignalR protocol on the server yourself. It is documented at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/SignalR/docs/specs.

Comment: Are you familiar with an existing open source implementation?

Comment: Yeah, the .NET implementation
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/SignalR/server